# How can I parse a string param in a mixin, or maybe, a way to remove the quotes from the resulting css? (.scss - SASS)

Tags: sass

Im extremely newbie in SCSS (or anyother kinda of coding rs) was just playing sass, then I stopped in a problem.

I was trying to use a mixing for multiple shadows to a box-shadow, how we all know in the tradicional css, it should be like that:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #333, 0 0 10px #222
```

Then I've coded this mixin:

```
@mixin set_shadow($shadows){
  -moz-box-shadow:$shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow:$shadows;
  box-shadow:$shadows;
}
```

and the result was almost what I wanted:

```
-moz-box-shadow: "0px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 3px black";
-webkit-box-shadow: "0px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 3px black";
box-shadow: "0px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 3px black";
```

Buuut... sadly..

The quotes don't allow code works

How can I parse a string param in .scss (SASS), or one way to remove the quotes from the resulting css?

Comment: You may want to look into [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), which has—among other things—all of the CSS3 vendor prefixes and all that taken care of. It will save you time. For example: [`@include box-shadow()`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/#mixin-box-shadow). It is even smart enough to take a bunch of shadows without quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the  [`unquote()`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) function is what you are looking for:

```
@mixin set_shadow($shadows){
  -moz-box-shadow: unquote($shadows);
  -webkit-box-shadow: unquote($shadows);
  box-shadow: unquote($shadows);
}

h1 {
  @include set_shadow("0 1px 1px #333, 0 0 10px #222");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [variable arguments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments). And then pass an unquoted list of shadows.

```
@mixin set_shadow($shadows...){
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
}

h1 {
  @include set_shadow(0 1px 1px #333, 0 0 10px #222);
}
```

Comment: not able to test it now, but thank you, soon, I'll post the results